# Boost Python No to_python for std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, python, boost, c++11, boost-python

I have a problem with boost.python that I can't solve.
I tried to expose a class including a function that returns a `std::unique_ptr`.

The signature looks like: `std::unique_ptr<MyClass> myFunc() const;`

I exposed the function and got the following error when calling `myFunc()` in python:

`TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: std::unique_ptr<MyClass, std::default_delete<MyClass> >`

I tried to solve the error by also exposing the pointer with the following code:

```
class_<std::unique_ptr<MyClass, std::default_delete<MyClass> >, boost::noncopyable ("MyClass", init<>());
```

Which compiles without any errors, but still produces the same error.

Am I missing something?